# repeating a sequence in system verilog assertion

Tags: system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I need to check for a sequence till end of simulation, after the initial match.

```
property check_at_fall;
@(posedge clk) 
    $rose(enable) ##[1:$] $fell(enable) |-> ##[0:2] ch_sel_seq [*1000]   ;
endproperty
assert_TELEMETRY : assert property (check_at_fall)
else `uvm_error("ADC_if",$psprintf("unexpected sequence "))
```

What I want is something like `[*$]` instead of `[*1000]` above. I don't want to give a huge number, I want to run it forever.

Comment: You can try something like `ch_sel_seq[*1:$] ##0 1'b0;` It will tell you when `ch_sel_seq` fails, but the assertion will never be complete. This may be a concern in your coverage collection.

Answer (score 0):

From SystemVerilog 1800-2012 page 359:

To specify a finite, but unbounded, number of iterations, the dollar sign ( $ ) is used. For example, the repetition

```
a ##1 b [*1:$] ##1 c
```

Moreover, [*] is an equivalent representation of [*0:$] and [+] is an equivalent representation of [*1:$].